# Create a custom scrollable collection view that mimics the behaviour of UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have this task that I need to create a custom scrollable view with 3 different types of cells from scratch.(no UICollectionView nor UITableView)

I have no idea what is the best way to start. Wether I should subclass UIScrollview or ...

Any guidance or direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create object of `UIView`, keep adding in `UIScrollView` depends on your array count.

Keep dynamic calculation for next `UIView` add subview in `UIScrollView`

Put transparent `UIButton` on `UIView` or use touch gesture to implement like `didSelectedRowAtindex`.

Another solution we can adapt when there is no UITableView.

Comment: Can you explain "keep adding in UIScrollView" a bit more?

Comment: "keep adding in UIScrollView" means.

- Maintain a variable totalHeight.

- Once a new ui element is created add added add its height to the variable.

- create all the elements to final value will give desired scrollview size.

- set that totalheight to scrollview's content size property.

Comment: True @RamaKrishnaChunduri

Answer (score 0):

Both TableView and Collection View inherits from UIScrollView. So using the parent class could be efficient. But inheritence also serves independent extensions it would also be ok to use the sub classes.

So, Decision depends on what you do. Here in your case.

- If one of the cells include a text field for user entry, then scrollview could do better as it offers convienience to scroll/shrink/retain the current UI while showing all the content of UI even when keyboard is present.
- If the cells only involve fields like labels,switches,indicators etc then tableview is the choice.
- If the cells has non-consistent or non free flow sections then collection view could be better.